# Web Site Working in All Browsers Except Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a new responsive site I'm building and the site's header renders just great in all browsers except Internet Explorer 9.

This puzzles me because I thought IE9 was more standards compliant.

If I put IE9 in IE8 compatibility mode, it again renders fine.

Any insight would be extremely helpful!  I'm really stumped and perhaps it's an easy fix.

Site Address:  **http://www.kent.edu/JMC**

IE 9 Screenshot:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvv5sksm3rbajlc/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-30%20at%206.44.35%20PM.png

Chris H.

Comment: What means "great" and why IE9 isn't "great". Please, clarify...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your doctype from `XHTML` to `HTML 4.01`

#### Recomended

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

You can also try forcing Internet Explorer to render in ie8 mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Comment: I was thinking of trying that, although it seems like a band aid on an underlying problem with my CSS.  Thanks though.

Comment: I believe IE is trying to parse you rules the wrong way because of doctype